# regex search remove word

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I want **remove** first 4 words from paragraph

Original :  `Mywebsite 21 12 34 have 10000 traffic`

What i want result  : `have 10000 traffic`

i have 1000 of line same as original paragraph ( `Mywebsite 21 12 34 have 10000 traffic`)

i have regex search code which is work like this :

Below code is remove first word from sentence :

```
^\w+\s+(.*)  = replace with $1
```

Following code will remove all numbers from line :

```
[0-9 ]+  = replace with space
```

I want combine above code, and make one regex search code work as i explain above, but not to affect any other words same line .

Comment: Try `^\w+\s[\d\s]+` and replace with empty string, `re.sub(r'^\w+\s[\d\s]+', '', text)`

Comment: Or try removing 4 times non whitespace chars followed by a tab or space `^[\t ]*(?:\S+[ \t]+){4}` https://regex101.com/r/CyUYh0/1

Comment: Perfect !! its work like charming , Thank you very much !

Comment: http://regex.inginf.units.it/ 
This is a good tool to build regex.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'^(\w+\s)[\d\s]+', r'\1', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W3fITf/2) a
The pattern will match

- `^` - start of string
- `(\w+\s)` - Capturing group 1: one or more word chars and a whitespace
- `[\d\s]+` - 1+ whitespace or digit chars.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/by2TbE):

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r"^(\w+\s)[\d\s]+")
s = "Mywebsite 21 12 34 have 10000 traffic"
print( rx.sub(r"\1", s) ) # => Mywebsite have 10000 traffic
```

Comment: ^\w+\s[\d\s]+  This one work perfect , how could i remove only numbers after first word example 21 12 34  ?  but only that numbers

Comment: @GayanFernando See the updated solution, please consider accepting if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your lines are all in the exact same format, i.e. if you always need to remove the first 4 words you can do something like this which is way simpler to understand than a RegEx:

```py
# Iterate through all your lines
for line in lines:

    # Split the line string on spaces to create an array of words.
    words = line.split(' ')

    # Exclude the 4 first words and re-join the string with the remaining words.
    line = ' '.join(words[4:])
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern that you tried `^\w+\s+(.*)` matches 1+ word chars, 1+ whitespace chars and then any char except a newline until the end of the string so that will match the whole string.

To remove the first word and the following 3 times 2 digits, you might use:

```
^\s*\w+(?: \d{2}){3}\s*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?: \d{2}){3}` Repeat 3 times matching a space and 2 digits
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vpscJw/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/0p1uAZ)

Note that `\s` also matches a newline. If you only want to match spaces or tabs you could use `[ \t]` instead.

Comment: Thank you , ^\w+\s[\d\s]+ this one work perfect ! however now i want remove only that numbers just after first word  , example  Mywebsite have 10000 traffic ?

Comment: Actually i after crack (?: \d{2}){3}\s*  this one work for me .  becoz i also want to remove only numbers